# Cannot get the .val of the jHTML textarea?

Tags: jquery, forms, firefox, jhtmlarea

I'm currently trying creating a form.

I have added a WYSIWG editor. The editor I used was the jHTML area.

When applying the WYSIWG editor to the textarea getting the value of the textarea using the jQuery .val function does not return a value when ran in Firefox.

This process works in Google Chrome but not in Firefox.

The code I am currently using is:

```
$('form#AddPages').submit(function() {
alert($('#PageTextArea').val());
return false;
});
$(function() {
$('.Template_tbl tr td a').lightBox();
$(".txtDefaultHtmlArea").htmlarea(); // Initialize jHtmlArea's with all default     values
});
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: `$('#PageTextArea').textarea.val()`